# Can I change my return ticket

Tags: air-travel, tickets, international-travel

I booked Turkish Airline from Accra to Istanbul and Istanbul to Accra.

But I am Argentina passport holder and visa free to Europe, can I change my return ticket from Istanbul to Paris or Berlin instead of Accra??

Comment: Whether the ticket you bought allows such changes is a commercial matter between you and the airline -- it doesn't have any clear connection to your nationality. Have you called the airline (or the agent you booked the ticket through, if any) to ask if you can change the ticket and what it will cost you? Adding an inbound leg from Paris/Berlin to Istanbul is probably going to increase the fare.

Comment: Whether the itinerary can be changed, and whether any fees and/or re-faring applies, is a matter of the fare rules and your contract with the airline. As Henning notes, you should contact Turkish Airlines who are final arbiters anyway about whether they will permit this or not, and what it will cost.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe.

We don't know what fare you purchased or what terms it carries. Change fees and policies vary depending on the fare you paid. The only way to find out is to contact your airline or travel agent and ask them to price the change, which will also depend on the exact dates and times you wish to travel. You will likely have to pay a change fee and any difference in fare.

It's also worth pricing out whether it is cheaper to purchase a new separate ticket to Paris or Berlin instead of changing your return ticket, e.g. on a low-cost carrier like Pegasus out of SAW airport.